# C# TCP server listen to multiple ports

Tags: c#, network-programming, tcplistener

I am using code below which was created by Rick Miller (Pulp Free Press). I need to receive data on multiple ports, to open independent threads for each port.

Tried to use new Thread(Listener(10000)).Start(); but it didn't work as expected.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;

public class MultiThreadedEchoServer {
public static void Main() {
    Listener(10000);
}

private static void Listener(int port) {
    TcpListener listener = null;
    try {
        listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, port);
        listener.Start();
        Console.WriteLine("MultiThreadedEchoServer started...");
        while (true) {
            Console.WriteLine("Waiting for incoming client connections...");
            TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
            Console.WriteLine("Accepted new client connection...");
            Thread t = new Thread(ProcessClientRequests);
            t.Start(client);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
    } finally {
        if (listener != null) {
            listener.Stop();
        }
    }
}

private static void ProcessClientRequests(object argument) {
    TcpClient client = (TcpClient)argument;
    client.ReceiveBufferSize = 4096;

    try {
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(client.GetStream());
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(client.GetStream());
        string s = String.Empty;
        while (!(s = reader.ReadLine()).Equals("Exit") || (s == null)) {
            Console.WriteLine("From client -> " + s);
            writer.WriteLine("From server -> " + s);
            writer.Flush();
        }
        reader.Close();
        writer.Close();
        client.Close();
        Console.WriteLine("Closing client connection!");
    } catch (IOException) {
        Console.WriteLine("Problem with client communication. Exiting thread.");
    } finally {
        if (client != null) {
            client.Close();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Did you delete you posting from yesterday?  I gave answer to use Async Socket and send back on the same socket that you receive message.

Comment: Yes, I did because I found a solution. Now I have a new question. Program listens to a single PORT (10000), I need to modify code to make it listen to multiple ports.

Comment: Important question: if you're talking about multiple ports, I'm thinking you're going to be wanting to run more than a handful of inbound connections; the code shown uses thread-per-connection, which is going to be *terrible* for anything at non-trivial scale. So: *are* you trying to do anything non-trivial in scale? As for the actual question: "use a separate listener per port" - done. I agree with @jdweng that async would be the way to go with this either way, but honestly: I'd just use Kestrel here, and let it worry about the socket layer, and I'll just tell it the ports I care about.

Comment: for example, here's a toy (meaning: not serious, don't use it in production) redis server based on Kestrel - here listening on 6379 (the redis port) for raw socket IO with a custom handler, and a basic http server on 5000, but you can see how easy it would be to add additional ports for whatever you want: https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/main/toys/KestrelRedisServer/Program.cs

Comment: nit: "Did you delete you posting from yesterday?" / "Yes, I did because I found a solution." - the really nice thing to do there would have been to add your solution to your question and leave it there, to help other people the same way that we're trying to help you

Comment: No changes are needed.  A Listener automatically listens to more than one connection.  But you need to use the ASYNC method to capture each new new connection so you can send back to same client.  Every time the accept method is called in the asyn you get the new socket (connection to client).  Then you can make a list of these sockets to return data.  I often use a dictionary and get the remote end point of each connection so I can send message to any connection.

Comment: @jdweng a `TcpListener` listens for connect attempts on a single *port* - and all it does here is accept connections and hand those off to threads; OP wants to listen to multiple ports, so they'll need multiple listeners and accept loops.

Comment: @MarcGravell : Multiple ports could be multiple port numbers or multiple connections on same port number.  The OP is not clear. I usually interpret a port as a single port number with multiple connectionsunless specifically asked for multiple port numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Tried to use `new Thread(Listener(10000)).Start();` but it didn't work as expected.

The expression `Listener(10000)` returns `void`, so you can't use that as an argument; what you need is a `ThreadStart`, so:

```cs
new Thread(() => Listener(10000)).Start();
```

For a small number of ports, thread-per-port isn't too terrible, but I will emphasize that the code shown is thread-per-client, which will scale *terribly*; this is not a good way to write a server, except for trivial things that will only have a handful (as in: less than 10) of well-behaved clients.

Comment: Thank you! It is exactly what I need. I am working on TCP listener for connection of GPS trackers. Program will wait for connections on 100-500 different ports, each port is dedicated to unique device. Each port will be receiving thousands of data packets. So now I am looking for suitable solution.

Comment: @LastCodeLine how many clients are we talking about here? 100-500 ports suggests very high numbers of clients, in which case: please immediately stop using threads - that is *not* a scalable solution. Now, async socket IO is possible, but the API is horrible - honestly: Kestrel and pipelines is the way to go here. See that code I linked to in the comment on the main question, or my multi-part blog series here: https://blog.marcgravell.com/2018/07/pipe-dreams-part-1.html

Comment: I strongly agree with Marc Gravell. Having 100 or even 500 threads is a horrible design which will drag down your programs performance. Like he mentioned why not use a proper server like Kestrel which has all the problems and cahhlenges regarding handling hundreds of clients already solved?

Comment: This method should be used? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/asynchronous-server-socket-example

Comment: @LastCodeLine no, not really; that API is a legacy one; for TCP servers I'd 100% say "use Kestrel"; for UDP, there are better ways - if you let me know your GitHub (by email, presumably), I'll add you to a private repo that shows this